# ADF pipeline system variables for meta data tracking

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm currently working on a stored procedure script to pull all the pipeline and system variables and insert them into a control table for auditing and monitor purposes, however struggling to find the correct variable for two values @run and @run_id. Run in this context is the value in the ADF monitor page for whether a pipeline run is original or a rerun: [image: See example on the Monitor page]

**Solved the second query, see comments:** <s>The second value is the run_id, as returned by @activity('Sample Copy Activity').output.RunId, but placed within a for loop. At the moment this returns the pipeline's RunID, but I'd like to obtain the Copy Activity's ID.</s> [image: See example of stored procedure in the for loop]

<s>The @pipeline().GroupId returns the same value as the above output.RunId, so unsure how the RunId and GroupId variables differ?</s>  Any advice, pointers to documentation or values for the what to enter into the stored procedures parameters in the second image. Thank you!

I've checked the Azure Documentation in detail, searched various forums and stack overflow for a complete list of system and pipeline variables and tested all provided parameter/variable names. Can only assume that the documentation is not complete or the values are not able to be ontained.

Comment: Solved half of the query: Answer for value two (Activity Run ID): is @activity('MyActivity').ActivityRunId
as found on MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a5400c3a-2a15-4648-9337-be8ed58e69da/current-activity-runid?forum=AzureDataFactory

This parameter returns the correct activity run ID within or outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, In ADF there is no particular API that has this property(**Run - original or Rerun**).

But you can try by getting the logs by **Diagnostics settings of ADF**(I have not tested).

Create a storage account in same Data factory and select archive to storage account.

[image]

Select storage account or send to log Analytics workspace and get that using ADF.

[image]